# How to replace url hyphen(-) with underscore(_) in CodeIgniter 4

Tags: codeigniter-4

$routes->setTranslateURIDashes(true);

I have tried this method in routes.php file but it's not working. Plz help

Answer (score 0):

Add to app/config/Routes.php:

```
$routes->setTranslateURIDashes(true);
```